# How to improve the loading speed of a PDF that contains lots of pictures

Tags: pdf, pictures

I have a PDF file that contains only scanned pictures(from academic papers). It has about 90 pages, and is around 6MB. When I open it in a PDF reader, especially on iPad/iPhone, it lags heavily. It usually takes about 3sec to load a page. Even on a PC with SSD, the reading experience is still not perfect.

Is it possible to improve/optimize its loading speed? The scanned page is all black and white, and contains mostly text and math equations. I don't think OCR will work in this case due to the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe Acrobat has optimization for scanned documents, as well as a regular optimization.  Down sampling the images and fast web view may help.